# Why MaxTouch amtel_mxt_ts driver can't register interrupt on Yocto BeagleBone am335x?

Tags: yocto, interrupt, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I need to integrate a Maxtouch Touchpanel (atmel_mxt_ts) Driver to an BeagleBoneBlack based Yocto Dunfell 3.1 with linux-ti-staging Kernel 5.4 system. The driver is set as loadable kernel module. The Yocto project integrates meta-ti and meta-arm from the dunfell branches.

The Interrupt should use gpio0[30] at address 0x870 on the BeagleBones P9 header. For that I set the mode ofthe gpio to 7.

I wrote a DTS to the sources and add the resulting DTB it to be loaded at startup. So far everything is working. The DTB is created and loaded during boot up.
The only problem is that when the driver is loaded by the kernel it complains about to be unable to register the interrupt.

**[    2.823173] atmel_mxt_ts 1-004a: Failed to register interrupt**

**[    3.040633] atmel_mxt_ts: probe of 1-004a failed with error -22**

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

This is my main DTS file

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Jumpnow Technologies, LLC - http://jumpnowtek.com
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */

/dts-v1/;

#include "am33xx.dtsi"
#include "am335x-bone-common.dtsi"

#include "bbb-i2c1.dtsi"
#include "bbb-dcan1.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "TI AM335x BeagleBone Black";
    compatible = "ti,am335x-bone-black", "ti,am33xx";
};

&ldo3_reg {
    regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-always-on;
};

&mmc1 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
};

&mmc2 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&emmc_pins>;
    bus-width = <8>;
    status = "okay";
};

&am33xx_pinmux {

    touch_pins: touch_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_GPMC_WAIT0, PIN_INPUT_PULLDOWN, MUX_MODE7)   /* P9.11 0x870 Touch IRQ */
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_MCASP0_AXR0, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE7)   /* P9.30 0x998 Touch RST */
        >;
    };

    can_pins: can_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_UART1_TXD, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE2)  /* P9.24 0x984 CAN rx */
            AM33XX_PADCONF(AM335X_PIN_UART1_RXD, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP, MUX_MODE2) /* P9.26 0x980 CAN tx */
        >;
    };
};

&dcan0 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&rtc {
    system-power-controller;
};

&i2c1 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    
    atmel_mxt_ts@4a {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "atmel,atmel_mxt_ts";
        reg = <0x4a>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio0>;    /* P9.11 gpio0
        interrupts = <30>;         /* gpio0[30], Falling edge only 0x02*/
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&touch_pins>;
    };
};

&i2c2 {
    status = "okay";
};

&dcan1 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&can_pins>;
};
```

and this is the content of bbb-i2c1.dtsi

```
&am33xx_pinmux {
    i2c1_pins: i2c1_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x958, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE2)  /* P9.18, i2c1_sda */
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x95c, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE2)  /* P9.17, i2c1_scl */
        >;
    };
};

&i2c1 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins>;
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
};
```

and this is the content of bbb-dcan1.dtsi

```
&am33xx_pinmux {
    dcan1_pins: dcan1_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x984, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE2)   /* P9.24, ddcan1_rx */
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x980, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE2)  /* P9.26, ddcan1_tx */
        >;
    };
};

&dcan1 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&dcan1_pins>;
};
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug by myself. It was a missing closing command  tag here

```
   interrupt-parent = <&gpio0>;    /* P9.11 gpio0
```

I opened a multiline comment without closing and all included attributes were not set